# Python and Pandas - Sorting by Date

Tags: python, pandas, alpha-vantage

What I've tried for a sort "should" be working; but it is not.

I've queried the "Alpha Vantage" API using the "alpha_vantage" Python library.  Below is my code.  I am requesting to sort by date; but, as you can see from the output in the df.head() the sorting by date is in the wrong direction.  However, the plot is going in the right direction.

```
df, meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol='AAPL',outputsize=365)
df['4. close'].plot()
plt.title('Intraday Times Series for the AAPL stock (5 min)')

# Attempting sort here!  Also I've tried df.sort_values(by=['date'])
df.sort_values(by=['date'])  
print(plt.show())
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
None
date         1. open  2. high  3. low  4. close   5. volume

2019-11-13   261.13   262.95  261.07  262.4307   3284781.0

2019-11-12   261.55   262.79  260.92  261.9600  21826100.0

2019-11-11   258.30   262.47  258.28  262.2000  20455300.0

2019-11-08   258.69   260.44  256.85  260.1400  17496600.0

2019-11-07   258.74   260.35  258.11  259.4300  23735100.0
```

Comment: `sort_values` does not work in place. `df = df.sort_values(by=['date'])` instead. No sorting has taken place here so presumably the API returns the values in a sorted manner already (or a coincidence), but in the opposite direction than you want: `df = df.sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=False)` is needed there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df = df.sort_values(by=['date'])`

should get it done